# Where is the pow-mod function defined in Elisp

Tags: lisp, elisp

I would like to use the pow-mod function to help call perform modular arithmetic on 'bigpos' numbers.

I found it on this elisp documentation [website](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Computational-Lisp-Functions.html#Computational-Lisp-Functions)

However when I call pow-mod, I cannot even get it to be recognized:

```
(require 'calc)
(require 'calc-ext)
(pow-mod message-encoded e n)
```

But it's not recognized! I'm confused because it's listed under computational lisp functions. So I assume that it was a part of the 'calc' functions. What is wrong? Is there some library I am missing? I tried `(require 'pow) but to no luck.

Where is pow-mod defined? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
(math-pow-mod 19 103 89)
```

(In the documentation you linked, go up one level to 17.5.7 and check the first paragraph: "These functions are shown by their names as they conventionally appear in defmath. Their full Lisp names are generally gotten by prepending ‘calcFunc-’ or ‘math-’ to their apparent names.")

Comment: This works, but apparently this won't work with bigpos numbers. So now I need to find something else. Thank you though!

Comment: Do you mean "it doesn't produce correct results with some inputs" or "it gives errors"? I just tried `(math-pow-mod '(bigpos 394) '(bigpos 193) '(bigpos 19))` and got the correct result.